# Deleting duplicates, keeping lowest value in different column

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Reference Image]

Hey all,
i'm trying to find a way, in VBA, to setup a delete statement that will delete the entire row for duplicates in column M while keeping the lowest value in column E. In the image above I've highlighted, in green, the rows I would like to keep. Any push in the right direction on how to delete these unwanted duplicates in VBA would be greatly appreciated!

I was thinking of an If else then but I'm not sure that is the best direction.

Comment: Deke, can you add another column where to do a calculation?

Comment: Yeah I have room to add columns for calculations if needed. anything after N is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a column where you could check if PPFROM (the value) is the min of the group (ARTICLE).

Please adjust the references inside the formula.

[image]

This is the formula:

```
=IF(MINIFS($E$4:$E$10;$M$4:$M$10;M4)=E4;"Keep";"Delete")
```

After that you can filter by the new column and delete the rows marked with "Delete".